# Replacing hard coded string with String variable which has slashes

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code where i tried to replace the dump path by the variable "**dumppath**" which has same exact characters as in the string which i have in the command but when I replace it by the variable, it always gives me a IOException where it says **The system cannot find the file specified**. But with the hard coded path it works fine.

```
public String dumppath = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump";

public void backupDatabase() {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

        try {

            int processComplete; // to verify that either process completed or not

            //Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("'"+dumppath+"' -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
// call the mysqldump in terminal and execute it
            processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();//store the state in variable

            if (processComplete == 1) {//if values equal 1 process failed

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Failed");//display message
            } else if (processComplete == 0) {//if values equal 0 process failed
                System.out.println("Backup up : "+backuppath);
                System.out.println("Dump Path : "+dumppath);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n Backup created Successfully..\n Check the Backup File in the D: Directory named as backup.sql");
//display message
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);//exeception handling

        }

// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: Your title seems to imply the strings are different.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils What's the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "'"+dumppath+"' -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
```

is same as

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
 "'C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump' -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
```

which has two more single quote when compared with the hard coded string.

To obtain the original string, you should try something like

```
String dumppath = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump";
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( dumppath+" -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
```

or

```
String command = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql";
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.6.12\\bin\\mysqldump -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
 Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   "'"+dumppath+"' -u root mysql -r F:/backup.sql");
```

The first of these calls does not have single quotes around the path.

Comment: If you don't need the single quotes, remove them.